# Proper way to send callback for both result and error - ES6 - JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I was wondering how can I properly display errors and results on ES6.

Basically this code here works:

```
db.collection('Videos').findOneAndUpdate({
  name: 'Funny Video.mov'
}, {
  $set: {
    format: 'mp4'
  }
}, {
  returnOriginal: false
}).then((result) =>{
  console.log(result);
});
```

When I try to add error and result callbacks even if I pass the wrong info it doesnt show the error. See this code:

```
// THIS DOESNT WORK
db.collection('Videos').findOneAndUpdate({
  name: 'Funny Video.mov'
}, {
  $set: {
    format: 'mp4'
  }
}, {
  returnOriginal: false
}, (err, result) =>{
  if(err){
    console.log('Unable to update..');
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

Same here. I used then here and it works.

```
// THIS WORKS
db.collection('Videos').find({name: 'Home Video.mp4'}).toArray().then((result) =>{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));
});
```

But if I add an error callback it doesnt. See this code:

```
// THIS DOESNT WORK
db.collection('Videos').find({name: 'Home Video.mp4'}, (err, result) =>{
  if(err){
    console.log('Cannot find that video');
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));
}).toArray();
```

Any idea how and why?

Comment: I don't get it. What API are you using ? In your working blocks, you are handling promises but not in your error handling ones. If the API returns Promises, then why don't you handle the errors raising from these promises ? Ps: if it is mongodb, then add the tag [tag:mongodb]

Comment: tell me how. this is mongodb

Comment: I did it, but for next time, just click the [edit] link under your question, you can change the tags at the bottom.

Comment: do you know where this `then()` method comes from? What Object/Type it provides? What the API of this method and of this Type in general is?

Comment: @Thomas: its promises...ES6 JavaScript

Comment: Then what's the question? [read the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Answer (score 0):

Those methods return promises, don't try to pass node-style callbacks into them. Instead, supply an error handler as the [second argument to `then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
db.collection('Videos').findOneAndUpdate({
    name: 'Funny Video.mov'
  }, {
    $set: {
      format: 'mp4'
    }
  }, {
    returnOriginal: false
  })
.then(result => {
    console.log(result); // either this runs on fulfillment
  }, err => {
    console.log('Unable to update..'); // or this runs on rejection
  });
```